# Can a restore image of Windows 7 x64 (including two years of updates) be put on OneDrive?

Tags: windows-7, onedrive, system-restore

I have a Windows 7 x64 system and it has been regularly updated over a period of two years with Microsoft patches.  Is there a way of taking a "snapshot" of the system and storing that image on OneDrive, so it could be used to recover the system if the need to do so should ever arise? Windows Backup does not show OneDrive as a backup location.

Comment: This cannot be done with the current version of `Windows Backup` `OneDrive` didn't even exist in its current form when Windows 7 was released.  You would have to use a third-party imaging tool to create the image in the OneDrive folder so it can be synced.  This will take considerable amount of local storage though.

Answer (score 3):

Theoretically, you could use a program to create an image of your hard drive and store that somewhere. The problem will be that this image contains everything on your hard drive, including installed programs, etc. This will mean that the image itself is going to be massive. Although you could then store this file on a OneDrive location, it is going to be huge. You probably need to own an Office 365 license which comes with OneDrive Business with 1TB of storage (if my memory serves me right) to accomplish this, and the uploading will take days, if not weeks, depending on your connection.

Storing this image on a USB stick or external hard drive somewhere is probably a more sensible thing to do.

When making the image, out of experience, the best type of image you can make is a 1 on 1 image. Other backup software is used to retrieve files rather than restoring the exact image back. For restoring the exact image back, you need a 1 on 1 image. This does mean that the image itself is going to take up a lot of space. Compression is usually possible, but then it will take a long time to make the image. It is up to the software how well it performs and how the options work. There are many though and I don't have any recommendations regarding which software to use for making an image, because most software package I used for work cost money and I never needed one for private use.

Comment: Basically any `Office 365` subscription comes with unlimited `OneDrive` storage ( 1TB ).  As you point out the image itself will be massive.  Which means it will take extremely long time upload and a long time download.  In any case I wouldn't store my only copy on `OneDrive` for a several reasons.

Comment: @Ramhound thanks for clearing that up. I wasn't sure and couldn't find the exact details quickly about the limits.

Comment: I would agree, this is a really bad idea. If your internet connection is fast enough to make downloading an image file that is potentially in the hundreds of GB a realistic proposal, it's fast enough to make it much quicker to install a vanilla version of Win 7 and just pull the Windows Updates down afterward. Keep installers for your applications on a USB drive or two somewhere safe. Back up your documents to OneDrive. And what a great opportunity to de-cruft!

Comment: Wow Unlimited = 1TB now? Quick, someone tell science! ;)

Comment: @LPChip - Its an important distinction only because the Enterprise version of `Office 365` and specifically the Enterprise version of `OneDrive` uses SharePoint which has its own limitations.  Going forward that might change given Microsoft most recent comments on using the same syncing engine for both.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 - That is only the initial amount you are allocated.  I am specific because that allocation might change, but you get unlimited storage, but I don't entirely trust the word unlimited to begin with.

Comment: @Ramhound Yeah, agreed. Microsoft keeps changing this info. Sometime ago, it used to be 50 GB. :P But I also heard about 1TB from colleagues. So yeah. Their servers must have huge disks. LOL

Comment: [Here](http://blogs.office.com/2014/10/27/onedrive-now-unlimited-storage-office-365-subscribers/) is the release information for this particular change

Comment: @Ramhound That was the joke. No one should trust "Unlimited" storage. :)  I'm sure MS would have a problem if I started generating a stream of bogus data and uploading it directly. "But you said Unlimited! So you have to store my 5PBs of data." ;)

Answer (score -1):

There are a few limitations to note in answering this question:
**First**, OneDrive file limits have recently been changed to a 10GB maximum for file sizes(1). Chances are, your full system backup will be larger than that size. Our corporate Windows 7 64-bit images with updates, office, and basic software is a 16gb Wim file. This is smaller than the Ghost version of the image which comes in around 26gb, however, it is still too large for OneDrive.
**Second**, Windows 7 allows complete image backups to a network share, but not incremental updates(2).
**Third**, the transfer speeds would be very slow and would require you to copy them using a second system or external media any way to recover the data. Windows Recovery Environment (WinRE), which is the stock environment for recovering old backups, has no way of connecting to Onedrive to find the image and apply it to your system. This means that your best bet is to have and external hard drive to store your system backup and software installers.

To setup the external hard drive, I would suggest following the steps in this [TechNet - WinPE: Create USB Bootable drive](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825109.aspx) article. To create your full backup of your system I would suggest this [TechNet - Capture and Apply Windows, System, and Recovery Partitions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825041.aspx) article. This method will allow the WinRE environment to restore your Wim file image without needing to rely on third party software. If WinRE isn't working on your system, as would be the case if the drive it self died, then the remaining steps in that article will help you setup a new drive.

Once you have your backup, if you are really persistent about getting it saved to OneDrive, you could do a split zip file to break up the image into enough segments to be under the OneDrive file limitations and upload one at a time.

(1) [CNet http://www.cnet.com/news/microsoft-onedrive-to-boost-file-size-limit-to-10gb/#!](http://www.cnet.com/news/microsoft-onedrive-to-boost-file-size-limit-to-10gb/#!)
(2) [Wiki Backup and Restore http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backup_and_Restore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backup_and_Restore)

Comment: Its entirely possible to add the required resources for `WinRE` to do this itself.  The default WinRE does indeed not have the resources to upload data to `OneDrive` doesn't mean it can't be done.